# A problem with querying a graph with SPARQL on Bioportal

Tags: sparql

I am querying an ontology on the [Bioportal endpoint](http://sparql.bioontology.org/). The ontology (NIF) is stored as a graph, so I put it in the FROM clause as the endpoint instructed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF>
WHERE{ 
   ?p a rdf:Property
}
limit 100
```

However, as can be seen below, the results came back showing few properties related to NIF and others to a different ontology called SKOS (Simple Knowledge Organization System).
[image]

In the Bioportal documentation it is said it maps some properties to SKOS properties, so I thought maybe the results are fine.

However, I had to test if I am querying the correct graph. So I used the below code to count the number of nodes since I know the NIF has around 3.6 million triples!

```
SELECT (count (*) as ?nodes)
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF>
WHERE{ 
   ?s ?p ?o
}
```

This resulted in 7984 nodes with and without the FROM clause! So I guessed I should be using the "count" incorrectly!

So I wonder how I should make sure that I am just querying the NIF ontology. Also, how to count its nodes?

Thanks :)

Comment: "Our setup is configured to bind 8K elements per triple pattern." https://www.bioontology.org/wiki/SPARQL_BioPortal#Partial_or_Incomplete_Results

Comment: @StanislavKralin So? It also says in case of a problem, it will show a message! It showed no message! I don't get your comment.

Comment: So, now you try to use a public endpoint. What happened with loading all data into `rdflib` graph? Or, why are you not just setting up a local triple store and load the data into it? The BioPortal endpoint is just for demo purposes and not for production use.

Comment: moreover, I doubt that all the data is contained in the graph. You can easily see that only two properties `skos:prefLabel` and `skos:altLabel` are used: `SELECT distinct ?p
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF>
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o
}` - that is clearly **not** the whole NIF dataset. One more time, download all the data and load it into a local triple store, then use SPARQL

Comment: and if you search for "nif" in the BioPortal web interface, you will find 4 ontologies related to NIF. So at least you would have to use all those ontologies in the SPARQL query. And even, then no idea if this will contain the whole NIF dataset...

Comment: find all graphs: `SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {
  graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}
}
order by ?g`

Comment: `prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT distinct ?p
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF-RTH>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF-SUBCELL>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF_CELL>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF_DYSFUNCTION>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF_x1>
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
order by ?p
`

Comment: @AKSW I moved to Bioportal since my local machine couldn't load the ontology. Also, my VM is down for couple of days because of server problems and I need to get something done soon. I know there are different modules of NIF present on Bioportal (used the Filter clause to find them). But since it has a full version of NIF in its NIF webpage, thought that maybe it has the full one loaded too! I think the code you sent will help. Thank you.

Comment: any open source triple store (Fuseki, Virtuoso, etc.) is clearly able to load this small dataset. I mean, using BioPortal ok, but the endpoint is **not** for production. You don't have any cotrol over it, if the service is down, you're stuck again. It's always better to load it into your own triple store. And this small dataset doesn't need that many resources, I'd just load it into a local Fuseki.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you! I'll try that too.

Comment: @AKSW I am trying to use Fuseki as you mentioned. It seems it needs Apache Tomcat. Do you think I can use my local windows system (8GB memory) to load this 3.6 million triple ontology? Or do I need to use a VM with bigger memory? Because last time I wanted to use apache on the VM with Ubuntu I couldn't run it according to some permissions.

Comment: You don't need Tomcat. Fuseki has a standalone version, see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-run.html#fuseki-standalone-server - you can just start it from the command line. 3.6 million is not large, it should work

Comment: @AKSW I wanted to thank you! I have spent many days finding an app or platform on both Windows and Ubuntu to just start using SPARQL and had no chance! I started using Fuseki this morning and got the ontology loaded and working in less than 2 hours on my 8GB memory windows system! FINGERS CROSSED that nothing dodgy happens now! :))) And hopefully I'll be back with my SPARQL questions now! PS: i realized Blazegraph is just a copy of Fuseki! Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @RFNO yeah, Fuseki is a great community project from people knowing a lot of RDF/SPARQL and databases. For me, it's one of the easiest to use triple stores, though indeed there are others. Regarding Blazegraph being a copy of Fuseki, not sure what you mean, but Blazegraph is a very scalable graph database and for example the new *Amazon Neptune* is based on it now - it has nothing to do with Fuseki besides both being triple stores

Comment: @AKSW Aha, so I've been wrong about the Blazegraph! To me it looked very similar to Fuseki plus it was hard to get it to work. I didn't know about its other uses!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SERVICE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/#algebra_service_examples) keyword.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT (count (*) as ?nodes)
WHERE
{ 
   SERVICE <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF>
   {
      ?s ?p ?o
   }
}
```

If this fails, possibly the service you are connecting is not correct or up.
Try below example which connects to DBpedia:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT (count (*) as ?nodes)
WHERE
{ 
   SERVICE <http://DBpedia.org/sparql>
   {
      ?s ?p ?o
   }
}
```

By the way I can;t access URL http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIF. Seems to be unavailable or down.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried both, but it still shows the same 7984!

Comment: Did you try with DBpedia ? It is working for me. It basically connects to the service endpoint to query on its graph model.

Comment: Yes, still the same result! I even deleted all cookies since you said you go the result. Have you used this address: [BioPortal](http://sparql.bioontology.org) ?

Comment: @RFNO Please check if your SPARQL executor allow accessing via SERVICE command.

Comment: It doesn't seem so! I thought you use the endpoint I provided. May I ask which endpoint are you using?

Comment: I think this endpoint does not load other IRIs. Am I correct?

Comment: @RFNO I think so. However DBpedia one is working for me. Did you try that one ?

Comment: Yes. But querying DbPedia won't get me anywhere.

Comment: @RFNO I have edited my answer. I doubt that URL is working. Try accessing it.